# Can't work with Azure Blob Storage from .Net Core App

Tags: c#, azure-storage, .net-core-2.0

I want to use Azure Blob Storage to save some files.

For each file I have a submission date, which I also want to use to create a Container.  So I can organise the files by submission date.

I can access the Blob Storage and create the Container.

But I cannot set permissions on the Container, test if a particular Blob exists within it, or add a Blob to the Container.

What am I missing?

The innerException I'm getting in every case is:

> {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
>
> at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.<ExecuteAsyncInternal>d__4`1.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
>
> at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.<>c__DisplayClass64_0.<<SetPermissionsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
>
> Request Information
>
> RequestID:XXXXXX
>
> RequestDate:XXXXXX
>
> StatusMessage:This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
>
> ErrorCode:AuthorizationFailure
>
> ErrorMessage:This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
>
> RequestId:XXXXXX
>
> Time:XXXXXX
>
> }

Obviously an AuthorizationFailure as it says.  But I can access the Blob Storage and create a Container.  So what gives?

Here's the complete .Net Core 2 test program (minus a little redaction)

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System;

namespace AzureStorageTestApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var storageAccount = GetStorageAccount();

            var policy = new SharedAccessAccountPolicy()
            {
                Permissions = SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Read | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Write | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.List,
                Services = SharedAccessAccountServices.Blob | SharedAccessAccountServices.File,
                ResourceTypes = SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Service | SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Container,
                SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-15),
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24),
                Protocols = SharedAccessProtocol.HttpsOnly
            };

            var sasToken = storageAccount.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);

            var creds = new StorageCredentials(sasToken);

            var accountWithSAS = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, storageAccount.Credentials.AccountName, null, true);
            var blobClient = accountWithSAS.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            var containerName = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            if (container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Result)
            {
                var perms = new BlobContainerPermissions
                {
                    PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                };

                // Blows up here
                container.SetPermissionsAsync(perms).Wait();
            }

            var fileName = "testfile.txt";
            var fileData = "some file data";
            var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

            bool shouldUpload = true;
            // Blows up here
            var blobExists = blob.ExistsAsync().Result;
            if (blobExists)
            {
                blob.FetchAttributesAsync().Wait();
                if (blob.Properties.Length == fileData.Length)
                {
                    shouldUpload = false;
                }
            }

            if (shouldUpload)
            {
                // Blows up here
                blob.UploadTextAsync(fileData).Wait();
            }
        }

        private static CloudStorageAccount GetStorageAccount()
        {
            var connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<Redacted>;AccountKey=<Redacted>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

            return CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The same story - it just doesn't work (fails with auth error).

Use `CloudStorageAccount.Parse` with BLOB connection string:

```
CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=***;AccountKey=***;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");
```

Comment: You saved the day.. nothing else worked.. Yesterday was getting weird errors, today auth errors, but this worked for me ..Net Core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

OK so here's "the answer".

If you're using a CloudStorageAccount set up with a SharedAccessAccountPolicy (instead of actual credentials) then that CloudStorageAccount can only be used for storage account management itself.

So for instance you can create a Blob Container, but you cannot set the permissions on that container, for that you'll need an appropriately created SharedAccessBlobPolicy or actual credentials.

So far my answer is to throw away all the stuff I had set up to use the SharedAccessAccountPolicy, ending up with the following code at the start:

```
        var storageAccount = GetStorageAccount();

        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
```